# How to group multiple sets of values according to variable required amounts (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array, collections

Faced with a bit of a problem here that I think I may have stared at for too long, and I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.
I've been attempting some array manipulation that I feel like I've come close with a few approaches, but haven't gotten there yet.

What I'm after is this: Given an array of values (for this example I'll use simple values `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D')`, and a stated number of minimum required occurrences of each value, the ability to group the collections of these values of the required size. For example:

```
// when given this list of required amounts
var config = new[] {
    { Value: 'A', AmountRequired: 1 },
    { Value: 'B', AmountRequired: 2 },
    { Value: 'C', AmountRequired: 3 },
    { Value: 'D', AmountRequired: 4 }
};

// and this array of values (matches requirements exactly)
var values = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D' };

// the logic would return
var results = [
    ['A'],
    ['B', 'B'],
    ['C', 'C', 'C'],
    ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
];


// this array of values (with one extra of each value) would also return the same result
// because there aren't enough added values for a second combined group
var values = new[] { 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D' };
```

The use-case that's easiest to describe the behaviour is probably like a videogame crafting menu where you would see something like "You need 1 A, 2 B's, 3 C's and 4 D's to be able to craft this item", and so all you're interested in is how many complete sets of those values you have, any spares can be ignored.

I've attempted this using `Linq`, and I had it working when the required amount was the same for all fields, which obviously isn't going to meet all use cases. I wasn't planning on posting my code attempt here as I was hoping to get a fresh perspective on the problem, but I can make it available if it will help.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: Does the result need to be an array of arrays (like in your code snippet), or could it simply be an `int` saying how many complete sets exist in the source array? (For your example source array, the result would then be `1`)

Comment: @AstridE. I had been leaning that returning the data in the required format would maybe be most helpful for future use cases, but in the case I described above then an integer value would also be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that the result can simply be a count of complete sets.

---

I would suggest starting by creating an overview of the contents of your source array: How many times is each character present? A good tool for such an overview would be a dictionary.

First, the values in the source array need to be grouped. Then, a dictionary can be created based on these groups. The key for each `KeyValuePair` would the the char, and the value would be the occurrence count for that char:

```
var countPerChar = values
    .GroupBy(_ => _)
    .ToDictionary(
        charGroup => charGroup.Key,
        charGroup => charGroup.Count());
```

If your source array is this:

```
var values = new[] { 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D' };
```

, then `countPerChar` will look something like this:

> 

Then, I would create a dictionary to store the count of *complete sets per char*. This dictionary should contain as many entries as the `config` (and all keys in `config` should be present).

For each entry in `config`, I would try to get the value of the target char from `countPerChar`.

If the target char exists in `countPerChar`, the associated char count can be divided by the required amount to obtain the *complete set of the target char*.

If the target char does *not* exist in `countPerChar`, then the *complete set of the target char* is `0`.

```
var completeSetsPerChar = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (var entry in config.Where(c => c.AmountRequired > 0))
{
    countPerChar.TryGetValue(entry.Value, out int charCount);
    
    completeSetsPerChar[entry.Value] = charCount / entry.AmountRequired;
}
```

Now, to get the count of *complete sets*, you would simply take the minimum of all the *complete sets per char*:

```
var completeSets = completeSetsPerChar.Values.Min();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCUilb).

Answer (score -1):

I have also a solution that will tell u if a set is complete or not:

```
            // when given this list of required amounts
            var config = new[] {
                 new { Value= 'A', AmountRequired= 1 },
                new { Value = 'B', AmountRequired= 2 },
                new { Value = 'C', AmountRequired = 3 },
                new { Value= 'D', AmountRequired= 4 }
            };

            // and this array of values (matches requirements exactly)
            var values = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D' };

            var res =
                       from cfg in config
                       select (new { cfg.Value, setComplete = (values.Count(x => x == cfg.Value) >= cfg.AmountRequired) });

            res.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```